# exclude sub directory php

Tags: php, subdirectory

I want to list all files at directory and exclude sub directory (newfiles)

i tried to use (if($file != "newfiles") )
but no thing change

```
foreach (ListFiles("/data") as $key=>$file){

if($file != "newfiles"){ 
$files=array_pop(explode('/',$file)); 
$lfile[]=$files;
}

}


function ListFiles($dir) { 

    if($dh = opendir($dir)) { 

        $files = Array(); 
        $inner_files = Array(); 

        while($file = readdir($dh)) { 
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') { 
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) { 
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file); 
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else { 
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        closedir($dh); 
        return $files; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the directory tree ?

Comment: files (1-2-3-....-newsfiles)

Comment: newsfiles or newfiles ??

Answer (score 1):

if you want to list all files use this

```
`find /data -type f`
```

if you want to list all files and exclude directory called "newfiles" use this

```
`find /data/!(newfiles) -type f`
```

if you want to exclude also directory "badfiles"

```
 `find /data/!(newfiles|badfiles) -type f`
```

if you want files and directories

```
`find /data/!(newfiles)`
```

**WAIT** do not downgrade me. Its a shell executable of course,
in php you can run shell scripts like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('find /data/!(newfiles|badfiles) -type f');
print_r($output);
```

have fun

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it's `/data/newfiles` instead of just `/newfiles` because the **$file** variable returns the whole location instead of just the file name.

We check if the `$file` variable contain the string `data/newfiles`. If it matches, it means that the file is in the subdirectory.

We only add it to the `$lfile` array if it doesn't match which means files that are not in the `newfiles` subdirectory.

```
foreach (ListFiles("/data") as $key=>$file){
    /* Only continue if the $file variable doesn't have the string "data/newfiles" */
    if(!preg_match("/data\/newfiles/", $file)){ 
        $files=array_pop(explode('/', $file)); 
        $lfile[]=$files;
    }
}
```

`/data` points to the `data` folder in the filesystem root. I think you meant `./data`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below function to exclude directory you want

```
  function glob_deep($pattern, $exclude = array(), $flags = 0)
   {
     $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
     foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
     {
       if(!in_array($dir, $exclude)) {
          $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
       }
     }
  return $files;
  }
```

and call it like that

```
$files =  glob_deep('data', array('newfiles'));
var_dump($files);
```

hope this helps

Comment: how does this answer the question? it is neither recursive like his example nor does it exclude the directory he wants to exclude

Comment: directory has many other sub directories and I want to exclude one

Comment: the problem function listfile open all subdirectories and list all files,i need function ignore subdirectory and all files